# How to increase the distance between two columns in nomencl?

Tags: nomencl

I got trouble when i use the package of nomencl

When the symbol in the first column is long, how can I increase the distance between two columns in my nomenclature by virtue of package nomencl?

As shown in the following two pictures, when I use the nomencl package, the align is undesired, how can I achieve the performance just like the second picture?
[image: Undesired]
[image: Wanted]

At last, what do `\nomgroup{A}`, `\nomeqref{10}` mean in the `.nlo` file?

```
\begin{thenomenclature}
\nomgroup{A}
\item [{$\mathbf{A}$}]
\begingroup 
Compact form of state coefficient matrix
\nomeqref {10}
\nompageref{28}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enlarge the width for the "labels" using    `\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{<lenght>}`. The default is 1cm.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nocfg]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{2cm} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
 
\nomenclature{$\sigma\beta\gamma\delta\sigma\beta\gamma\delta$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
 \nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

To avoid the guessing you can use

```
\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{<longest label>}
```

for this example

```
\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{$\sigma\beta\gamma\delta\sigma\beta\gamma\delta$}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help！  By the way, do you know some syntax in `.nlo` file or `.nls` file? I just cannot figured out  what do `\nomgroup{A}`, `\nomeqref{10}`, `\nompageref{28}` mean, both inside and outside curly braces.

Comment: @KS.J This site works best with one question at the time, to benefit other readers. I suggest that you ask another question with this topic, and most important, add a compilable code that reproduce the output you mention.

Comment: OK, thank you for reminding me.